ACA Service URLs
my organization has decided to migrate our webservices from Google Cloud Run to Azure Container Apps. As a proof of concept, I have deployed a container app and am wondering how to 'ping' it programmatically. For context, in GCP every container had a service URL that looked something like https://container-name-xxxxxx-xx.a.run.app, and I am wondering if ACA's Application URL is similar.
Have spent quite a while creating an access token using my Continaer registries client id, client sercret and tenant ID, but cannot figure out why I can't ping my Application URL with a request module. I just get an unauthorized error.
Thanks

The Application URL in Azure Container Apps is similar to the service URL in Google Cloud Run. You can find the Application URL in the Overview page of the Container App in the Azure portal, or by using the Azure CLI command az containerapp show -g  -n  --query properties.configuration.ingress.fqdn.
If you are receiving an unauthorized error when pinging the Application URL, it is possible that your access token is not properly configured

The Application URL in Azure Container Apps is similar to the service URL in Google Cloud Run. You can find the Application URL in the Overview page of the Container App in the Azure portal, or by using the Azure CLI command  az containerapp show -g <resource-group-name> -n <container-app-name> --query properties.configuration.ingress.fqdn.

If you are receiving an unauthorized error when pinging the Application URL, it is possible that your access token is not properly configured. Double check that you have the correct client ID, client secret, and tenant ID for your container registry.
To Ping Azure Container Apps Programmatically,
First, ensure your container app is deployed in Azure with the correct configuration.

If your application requires Azure AD authentication, configure this through the Azure portal.
Obtain Azure AD Access Token. Go to Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory  (Entra ID) > App registrations > New registration.
Under the same App registration,
go to Certificates & secrets > New client secret. 


delegate permissions to access your container app. Collect your Directory (tenant) ID, Application (client) ID, and the client secret.
Next, make sure Python is installed and set up correctly.
pip install requests azure-identity


and install other modules if any missing.
Below is an example script
import requests
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

# Azure AD Credentials
tenant_id = "your-tenant-id"
client_id = "your-client-id"
client_secret = "your-client-secret"

# Resource details
app_url = "https://your-container-app-name.region.azurecontainerapps.io"  # Update this with your actual Container App URL

# Get an access token using Azure AD app registration
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
token = credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default")  # Use appropriate scope based on the API you are accessing

# Headers with Bearer token
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token.token}"
}

# Send a GET request to the Container App
response = requests.get(app_url, headers=headers)

# Print the response from the server
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Request succeeded!")
    print("Response body:", response.text)
else:
    print("Request failed with status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Error message:", response.text)

This script authenticates using Azure AD and sends a GET request to the specified Azure Container App. It includes error handling to output the response status and message.
References:

Build and deploy a Python web app with Azure Container Apps and PostgreSQL - Troubleshoot deployment

